# adding permissions to azure datalake gen1

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an instance of Azure Datalake Storage Gen1 structured as :

### folder structure

```
└── Tenants
    ├── Tenant-01
    │   ├── Product-A
    │   └── Product-B
    └── Tenant-02
        ├── Product-A
        └── Product-B
```

### team structure

there is a one to one mapping between

- Team-A owns Product-A
- Team-B owns Product-B

### permissions structure

Ideally I would want to give write permissions to Product-X for all tenants

- Team-A write access under `Tenants/**/Product-A/`
- Team-B write access under `Tenants/**/Product-B/`

and then potential read access like

- Team-A read under `Tenants/**/Product-B/`

### questions

- how can we achieve this without hitting the 32 ACLs limit and with large number of Tenant-* without writing out each ACL specifically.
- is this supported / how can this be migrated to Azure Data lake Storage Gen2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can leverage role assignable groups in AAD to have groups created
  for teamA and teamB and then assign required ACLS on those groups.
  This way we no need to add ACLs for each user individually.

  Please check below link to know how to create role assignable groups
  in Azure Active Directory- [Create Groups](http://You%20can%20leverage%20role%20assignable%20groups%20in%20AAD%20to%20have%20groups%20created%20for%20teamA%20and%20teamB%20and%20then%20assign%20required%20ACLS%20on%20those%20groups.%20This%20way%20we%20no%20need%20to%20add%20ACLs%20for%20each%20user%20individually.%20%20%20%20Please%20check%20below%20link%20to%20know%20how%20to%20create%20role%20assignable%20groups%20in%20AAD%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-create-eligible%20%20%20You%20can%20opt%20to%20keep%20the%20POSIX%20access%20control%20lists%20(ACLs)%20along%20with%20the%20data%20files%20while%20upgrading%20from%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1%20to%20Gen2%20or%20copying%20data%20between%20ADLS%20Gen2.%20See%20Access%20control%20in%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1%20and%20Access%20control%20in%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen2%20for%20additional%20information%20on%20access%20control.%20%20When%20you%20use%20ADF%20to%20preserve%20ACLs%20from%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen1/Gen2%20to%20Gen2,%20the%20existing%20ACLs%20on%20sink%20Gen2%27s%20corresponding%20folder/files%20will%20be%20overwritten.%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-acls)
- You can opt to keep the POSIX access control lists (ACLs) along with
  the data files while upgrading from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 to
  Gen2 or copying data between ADLS Gen2. See Access control in Azure
  Data Lake Storage Gen1 and Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage
  Gen2 for additional information on access control.

  When you use ADF to preserve ACLs from Data Lake Storage Gen1/Gen2 to
  Gen2, the existing ACLs on sink Gen2's corresponding folder/files
  will be overwritten.

  Preserve ACLs from Data Lake Storage Gen1/Gen2 to Gen2 | [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-acls)

Comment: one part of the question here is how to define a ACL like Tenants/**/Product-A (give access to Product-A folder and its contents to this group across all tenants)

would I still have to give access for each tenant-a/product-a combination for the group?